# Material3 AlertDialog has unwanted color behind rounded corners

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3, material3

I am migrating to Material 3 and my alert dialogs now have unwanted color under their rounded corners.

How can I remove that unwanted color and get the nice rounded dialogs?

[image]

I am using androidx.compose.material3.AlertDialog from version 1.0.0.

Here is the code of one of the dialogs

```
@Composable
fun NewClientSourceDialog(
    onDoNothingClick: () -> Unit,
    onImportClick: () -> Unit,
    onAddNewClick: () -> Unit,
) {
    AlertDialog(
        onDismissRequest = onDoNothingClick,
        text = {
            DialogText(id = R.string.clients_new_client_source)
        },
        confirmButton = {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(all = 8.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth(),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom,
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            ) {
                DialogButton(
                    onClick = onImportClick,
                    captionId = R.string.clients_import_contacts,
                )
                DialogButton(
                    onClick = onAddNewClick,
                    captionId = R.string.clients_create_from_scratch,
                )
                DialogButton(
                    onClick = onDoNothingClick,
                    captionId = R.string.clients_new_client_dismiss
                )
            }
        },
    )
}


@Composable
fun DialogButton(
    onClick: () -> Unit,
    @StringRes captionId: Int,
    destructive: Boolean = false,
) = TextButton(onClick = onClick) {
    Text(
        text = stringResource(id = captionId),
    )
}
```

Comment: can you post your code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue was caused by my theme configuration in `/res/values/themes.xml`

I had this auto-generated content in there:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. These colors don't affect the Composable functions, just the color
     of the Status Bar. For the colors used by the Composable functions, see Theme.kt -->
    <style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/status_bar</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/status_bar</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Changing it to

```
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar" />
</resources>
```

fixed the issue.